# Using ViewPager and replacing a fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im trying to create a 4 tabs application, where each tab is a fragment.
One tab is a search fragment and the second one is the results.
What I do is that once the search fragment 'send' button is clicked, the search params are sent to my results fragment and that fragment replaces the search fragment in the viewpager and gets displayed to the screen untill I hit back when viewing the results fragment.
In my ViewPager adapter I hold an array with all **5** fragments objects but my `getCount()` returns **4**. so I always have that results fragment as java object.
Im able to access the object by calling the viewPager's `getItem(4)` which isnt get called by the framework since `getCount()` returns 4. a bit hacky I assume but I understand that for inter-fragment communication I have to go through the viewPager's adapter.
I can live with that.

I have two issues remining:
1. How do I make the switch? I can have some function that tells the viewPager to save which fragment should be seen on that position, but how do I actually make the switch?
2. I assume that having the back button returning to the search fragment is exactly the same procedure. but to have the back button react that way only on my results fragment, I can implement the onBackPressed() in my results fragment?

my viewPager is probably the only thing relevant to show, and its a pretty standard as well:

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> _fragments;


    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        _fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        _fragments.add(new FragmentA());
        _fragments.add(new FragmentB());
        _fragments.add(new FragmentC());
        _fragments.add(new SearchFragment());
        _fragments.add(new ResultsFragment());
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int n) {
        if (n < _fragments.size())
            return _fragments.get(n);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you returning 4 from `getCount()`?

Comment: as I said, its a bit hacky, I know. because I want the results fragment to **replace** the search fragment, so I actually have 4 tabs but 5 fragments. In order to have the viewPager to show only 4 tabs, I did it, and my results fragment which is the last one, wont really get displayed, but it gets initiated and saved as an object for further use and inter-communication